# Search for values with no patttern in mySQL database

Tags: sql, mysql, performance, search

I have a table `users` with millions records, and I have fields like, phone number and document, and I need to validate an user with my API searching and matching his data, but the phone it's stored with no pattern, some rows has the correct pattern like
+00 (00) 00000-0000 and others it's 00 00000000, and I don't know how the user will insert his data to be validated, he can insert with the pattern or no.

I've tried to use a `REGEXP_REPLACE` in the query to always compare with the plain text, with no pattern, this way, I can guarantee that it will match the search for the correct data, but this approach can cust a lot of performance since my table has millions of data, even if one of these fields has an index.

How can I achieve that the result will match and I'll not sacrifice my app performance?

Comment: I’m wondering why you aren’t validating your data on input and storing it with a consistent pattern (or no pattern, patterns are normally how you display data, not store it)? Then you wouldn’t have this issue

Comment: I agree with you, but as I said, its a large database, already contains millions of registers and it's being stored this way for a long time..one way would be fix the way the input it's stored and apply the correction for all the data in the table. But assuming this is not possible now, there's any other way?

Comment: If you are going to have to transform the data at the point when you are making the comparison then the performance is always going to be impacted. If your DBMS supports functional index (and there’s a function that can standardise your data so it can be compared) then that might be a solution

Comment: A data sanitization project would probably be worth the effort.

Comment: Fix the data _before_ INSERTing it in the database.

Answer (score 1):

> *How can I achieve that the result will match and I'll not sacrifice my app performance?*"

Transform the data into standard formats *once*, and search that.

Cleaning up the data is expensive and error prone. If you have to do it every time, performance will be impacted as every query will have to look at every column. There are two options.

You can store the transform in a [functional index](https://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-index/mysql-functional-index/). A simple example, let's say you want to lowercase everyone's name. You can index `create index idx_lower_name ON people(lower(name))` so now when you have `where lower(name) = ?` it will use the index.

This is cheap and easy and works with your existing data, but limited. You're limited to transforms you can do with MySQL, more complicated transforms like standardizing phone numbers and addresses are difficult to nigh impossible. And you can't query this standardized data, you'll have to repeat the possibly complex transform: `select lower(name) from people where lower(name) = ?`.

Instead, it's better to fix the real problem...

> *I don't know how the user will insert his data to be validated, he can insert with the pattern or no.*

Standardization should be done at insert. Rather than every query having to do its own standardization (expensive and error prone and limited), you do it once on insert and queries thereafter can assume the data is clean. This is not limited to SQL, but to all programming.

This allows you to use libraries outside of MySQL to do the data transforms. For example, you can [use a programming library for making standard street addresses](https://github.com/street-address-rb/street-address) on your data before inserting.

Do the same transform on your existing data and update the existing rows. Then all your data is standardized and will remain standardized. Millions of records is not a lot. You can start start the process running in the morning and it will probably be done before the end of the day. Make sure you do this in batches of about 1000 each to avoid locking too many rows. Many SQL frameworks offer methods to make it easy to work in batches.

To be extra safe, make a new column for the standardized data and retain the original raw data, and be sure to index it. If anything goes wrong, you can simply drop the new standardized column. Once you've confirmed the transform has gone will, you can rename the columns and potentially drop the old one (or hang onto it if you feel you need the raw data).